# Flow formula evaluates to false

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, entry-criteria

[image]

when i run the flow in a debug mode I get this  -

The flow entry condition formula evaluated to false, so the flow didn’t run.

What am i missing ?

Comment: Can you share what the relevant values on the User you selected for the Debug run was? The values for `IsActive` and `UserRole.DeveloperName` specifically

Comment: You have "Only when the record is updated to meet the condition requirements" selected. Assuming this is correct for your use case, when you run the Debug feature, are you ensuring that the Role or IsActive field is getting changed when you set the values for the debugging user record? This will only run when one of those values is changed and meets the conditions.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Kranz !  The flow executed successfully after i  changed to 'Every time a record is updated and meets the condition requirements'.  I want the flow logic to execute only for certain user records  and not all user records.